# How to display field before title field in drupal 7

Tags: drupal

How to display field value before title  field in node view in particular cck in drupal 7

Comment: To get a good answer, you should provide much more detail. What value/title field, what node view, what's a CCK? What have you tried? what didn't work?

Comment: See: [Displaying a field before node title in Drupal 7](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/1553/displaying-a-field-before-node-title-in-drupal-7)

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, its not the order of the fields he want to change, but to display the value of a field before its name/title, which is not directly possible via admin/structure/types/manage/article/display. The possible values there are hidden, inline and above. I am not a themer, but just did a search, and found this: 
https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/1553/displaying-a-field-before-node-title-in-drupal-7
Starting from that answer its easy to reach your aim. If you have the devel module installed, enable the display $page array setting, then find the title you want to display and target it in your render expression.

Answer (score 0):

For e.g in article you want to display any field before title that go to admin-> structure -> content type. There you can find list of content type. there you can find manage fields for article content type. just click on that and you can find the list of fields in article content type.

Just drag and drop above any field and put it above title field.

Hope it helps.

Comment: have you got your answer @Mahender ?